# javascript input only letter

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

How to make a validation for a input only by letters (with spaces) with Javascript?

```js
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
     if(name == "")
     {
      alert("name is empty!");
            return false;
     }
        /*else if (...)
          {
           ...
          }*/
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Please use a search engine to find tutorials. Come back once you run into any specific problems and we (maybe) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression

```js
var name = prompt('Your name');
if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(name.replace(/\s/g, '')))) {
  alert("only letters!");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: @Wira See updated answer, does it solve your problem

Comment: it also helped, thanks in advanced.

Comment: @Wira It will validate name with spaces, upvote and accept the answer if solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

you can use Regular Expressions for this. look at the below example :

```
function validate(){
   var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
   if(name.match(/^[a-zA-Z_ ]*$/))
        {
            //Your logice will be here.
            alert("It's valid");
        }
        else{
            alert("Please enter only alphabets");
        }
   }
```

I Update the code to include space also

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/j1805c63/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: If my name is "Le Blond", it's show "Please enter only alphabets"

Comment: my bad, i mean it also can contain space

Comment: I Update the code to include space also @R3tep

Answer (score 0):

this is checking by keys above all those answer using regex

94 --> a

122 -->z

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){
        var inputValue = event.which;
        if(!(inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <= 120) && (inputValue != 32 && inputValue != 0)) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text'>
```

Also you can see those number from here what they are why this guy used [Link in here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm)

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: Your solution prevents user from deleting text or navigating in input field using keyboard... Also it's not possible to write uppercase letters.

Comment: Unable to enter a name with a space, like "Le Blond"

Comment: @Justinas i edited this for what he desire,could you remove your down vote because i am edited my answer and improved

Comment: @R3tep yeah same to you

Comment: @WiraXie this can be your accepter answer also because this can prevent it  to insert numbers which is your goal to achieve if this help check as accepted also

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar Sure, But jquery is not tagged on the OP

Comment: i think i can only check one answer so maybe i just give an upvote, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @R3tep Ops your right jquery is not tagged. But validation tagged i use key event validation using jquery so maybe

Answer (score -1):

Use Regular Expression `/[^a-z]/i` to check if there is non-letters characters:

```js
var name = prompt('Enter name');

if(name === false || name == "") {
  alert("name is empty!");
} else if (/[^a-z]/i.test(name)){
  alert("name is not valid!");
} else {
  alert("name is valid!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: If my name is "Le Blond", it's show "name is not valid!"

Comment: @R3tep Yes, because OP is only allowing letters: **only by letters**

Comment: @Justinas Mistake of Wira, You know that there are names with spaces ?

Comment: my bad, i mean it also can contain space